# Throwing error (exception) in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, joptionpane

I am working on a simple Java application. I have problem with throwing exception.

Actually, the exception should be thrown in thread. So there are threads where are these exception:

```
public void setVyplata(Otec otec) {

    try {
        otec.setVyplata(Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText()));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Nemozno vlozit string", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        otec.setVyplata(0);
        textField1.setText("0");
    }

}

public void setVyplata(Mama mama) {

    try {
        mama.setVyplata(Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Nemozno vlozit string", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        mama.setVyplata(0);
        textField2.setText("0");
    }
}
```

It is possible, both exceptions will be thrown at the same time.

And when it does, this is what I get:

[image: empty error message.... and my application stop working. i must close it trough task manager.]

i have thread running for each method. And my question is why will program stop working here. Because, when i start one of these threads separatedly. it works perfectly. When i start both threads there should be 2 error windows, but you can see blank error window and program not working.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Is it that you have a thread running for each method and that you need to get this Exception somewhere or simply that you need to know if you'll have two Dialogues? Or furthermore that you actually want to catch both errors on the same dialogue when both threads are running?

Comment: You catch the exception in order to not interrupt the execution of the program, so when you catch the exception you only interrupt the execution of that method, you have 2 different methods so you will have two different exception caught

Comment: Firstly thank you for reply.

@Joao Esperancinha

yes i have thread running for each method. And my question is why will program stop working here. Because, when i start one of these threads separatedly. it works perfectly.
When i start both threads there should be 2 error windows, but you can see blank error window and program not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can definatelly tell you that based on your previous comment that you are having a problem with the *not thread safe* characteristic of swing components. You should read the [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) documentation. You need to use the **invoke** methods to make sure your change tasks are placed on the event dispatch thread otherwise, yes, your application will crash.

An example for your code:

```
public void setVyplata(Otec otec) {

    try {
        otec.setVyplata(Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText()));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Nemozno vlozit string", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            otec.setVyplata(0);
            textField1.setText("0");
        });

    }

}

public void setVyplata(Mama mama) {

    try {
        mama.setVyplata(Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Nemozno vlozit string", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            mama.setVyplata(0);
            textField2.setText("0");
        });
    }
}
```

If you look in the SwingUtilities documentation you have a very good explanation of what [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) is actually doing:

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have
>   been processed. This method should be used when an application thread
>   needs to update the GUI. In the following example the invokeLater call
>   queues the Runnable object doHelloWorld on the event dispatching
>   thread and then prints a message.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This saved my day :)